# return php array from certain index and on

Tags: php

What is a function to return an array containing only elements from a certain index on?

so I have an array `$array = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')`

I want to return an array that looks like `('2', '3', '4')`

How do I do that using index 2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_slice`:

```
$array = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4');
print_r(array_slice($array,2));
```

Comment: @Jared - thanks. Copied the array declaration from the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you would like to [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) it?